# Drupal + CiviCRM: Contact form, add node/entityreference field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, civicrm

Is it possible somehow to put a node reference field on a CiviCRM contact form? Of course if it is solved for Entities, we have it for nodes.
I only saw solution for the opposite way with https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, at least not in any built-in way.  You could always do an integer field and build features that make it refer to a node ID, but CiviCRM isn't built to know about Drupal content.